# If G is a group such that all of its proper subgroups are abelian, then G itself must be abelian

Tags: group-theory

Is statement below true or false?

If G is a group such that all of its proper subgroups are abelian, then G itself must be abelian

Comment: If that was true, then it would follow immediately by induction on the order that all finite groups are abelian. Is that true?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What about $G = S_3$, the permutations of $3$ elements?

Comment: Indeed, the smallest finite nonabelian group is an obvious counterexample (even if one doesn't know that $S_3$ is the smallest nonabelian group)

Answer (score 7):

You can consider the quaternion group Q_8. All of its proper subgroups are cyclic and so abelian but the whole group Q_8 itself is not so. Preparing a subgroup lattice, you can see this easily.

Answer (score 4):

To generalize @Furor's post you can consider every **non-abelian Dedekind group** which is called *Hamiltonian Group*. For infinite example of it you can consider $$Q_8\times\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z(3^{\infty})$$

Comment: $Q_8\times\mathbb 1\times 1\le Q_8\times\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z(3^{\infty})$ is abelian?